# Does std::bind work with move-only types in general, and std::unique_ptr in particular?

Tags: c++, c++11, bind, unique-ptr

I'm trying to use boost::asio and run into a bit of a quagmire.

I'm trying to compile the following code:

```
std::unique_ptr<buffer_t> buffer = buffers.pop();
std::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&, size_t)> t = std::bind(&tcp_client::handle_read_done,
                                                                            this,
                                                                            std::placeholders::_1,
                                                                            std::placeholders::_2,
                                                                            std::move(buffer));
```

Everything works fine if I exclude the std::move(buffer), of course from both the signature of handle_read_done and as a passed argument in std::bind.

When trying to pass it into boost::asio::async_read_some it complains of implicitly deleted functions on the object returned from std::bind, on deleted functions on tuple which I assume are because of the movability, as well as a lot of boost specific errors. If I just try to assign it into a std::function which should match the signature that boost calls, I get those same tuple errors, so I guess they are the same ones. Just assigning the result of std::bind to auto yields no compiler error, but of course I can't call anything on it.

What am I doing wrong? Below is the output from when trying to assign to `std::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&,size_t)>`

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/functional: In static member function ‘static void std::_Function_handler<void(_ArgTypes ...), _Functor>::_M_invoke(const std::_Any_data&, _ArgTypes ...) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (rcon::net::tcp_client::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>(rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>, _ArgTypes = {const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int}]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/functional:2148:6:   instantiated from ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor, typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_integral<_Functor>::value), std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Useless>::type) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (rcon::net::tcp_client::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>(rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>, _Res = void, _ArgTypes = {const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int}, typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_integral<_Functor>::value), std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Useless>::type = std::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int)>::_Useless]’
/home/max/dev/rcon/src/net/tcp_client.cpp:98:34:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/functional:1778:2: error: no match for call to ‘(std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (rcon::net::tcp_client::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>(rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>) (const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int)’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/functional:1130:11: note: candidates are:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/functional:1201:2: note: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {_Args ...}, _Result = _Result, _Functor = std::_Mem_fn<void (rcon::net::tcp_client::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>, _Bound_args = {rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >}]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/functional:1215:2: note: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {_Args ...}, _Result = _Result, _Functor = std::_Mem_fn<void (rcon::net::tcp_client::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>, _Bound_args = {rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >}]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/functional:1229:2: note: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) volatile [with _Args = {_Args ...}, _Result = _Result, _Functor = std::_Mem_fn<void (rcon::net::tcp_client::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>, _Bound_args = {rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >}]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/functional:1243:2: note: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const volatile [with _Args = {_Args ...}, _Result = _Result, _Functor = std::_Mem_fn<void (rcon::net::tcp_client::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>, _Bound_args = {rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >}]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/functional: In static member function ‘static void std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_clone(std::_Any_data&, const std::_Any_data&, std::false_type) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (rcon::net::tcp_client::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>(rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>, std::false_type = std::integral_constant<bool, false>]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/functional:1652:8:   instantiated from ‘static bool std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_manager(std::_Any_data&, const std::_Any_data&, std::_Manager_operation) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (rcon::net::tcp_client::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>(rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/functional:2149:6:   instantiated from ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor, typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_integral<_Functor>::value), std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Useless>::type) [with _Functor = std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (rcon::net::tcp_client::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>(rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>, _Res = void, _ArgTypes = {const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int}, typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_integral<_Functor>::value), std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Useless>::type = std::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int)>::_Useless]’
/home/max/dev/rcon/src/net/tcp_client.cpp:98:34:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/functional:1616:4: error: use of deleted function ‘std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::_Bind(const std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>&) [with _Functor = std::_Mem_fn<void (rcon::net::tcp_client::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>, _Bound_args = {rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >}, std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)> = std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (rcon::net::tcp_client::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>(rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/functional:1189:7: error: ‘std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::_Bind(const std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>&) [with _Functor = std::_Mem_fn<void (rcon::net::tcp_client::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>, _Bound_args = {rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >}, std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)> = std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (rcon::net::tcp_client::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>(rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>]’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/functional:1189:7: error: use of deleted function ‘constexpr std::tuple< <template-parameter-1-1> >::tuple(const std::tuple< <template-parameter-1-1> >&) [with _Elements = {rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >}, std::tuple< <template-parameter-1-1> > = std::tuple<rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> > >]’
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/functional:56:0,
                 from /home/max/dev/rcon/include/net/tcp_client.hpp:4,
                 from /home/max/dev/rcon/src/net/tcp_client.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/tuple:249:17: error: ‘constexpr std::tuple< <template-parameter-1-1> >::tuple(const std::tuple< <template-parameter-1-1> >&) [with _Elements = {rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >}, std::tuple< <template-parameter-1-1> > = std::tuple<rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> > >]’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/tuple:249:17: error: use of deleted function ‘constexpr std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>::_Tuple_impl(const std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>&) [with long unsigned int _Idx = 0ul, _Head = rcon::net::tcp_client*, _Tail = {std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >}, std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...> = std::_Tuple_impl<0ul, rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> > >]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/tuple:170:17: error: ‘constexpr std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>::_Tuple_impl(const std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>&) [with long unsigned int _Idx = 0ul, _Head = rcon::net::tcp_client*, _Tail = {std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >}, std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...> = std::_Tuple_impl<0ul, rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> > >]’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/tuple:170:17: error: use of deleted function ‘constexpr std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>::_Tuple_impl(const std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>&) [with long unsigned int _Idx = 1ul, _Head = std::_Placeholder<1>, _Tail = {std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >}, std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...> = std::_Tuple_impl<1ul, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> > >]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/tuple:170:17: error: ‘constexpr std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>::_Tuple_impl(const std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>&) [with long unsigned int _Idx = 1ul, _Head = std::_Placeholder<1>, _Tail = {std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >}, std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...> = std::_Tuple_impl<1ul, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> > >]’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/tuple:170:17: error: use of deleted function ‘constexpr std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>::_Tuple_impl(const std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>&) [with long unsigned int _Idx = 2ul, _Head = std::_Placeholder<2>, _Tail = {std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >}, std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...> = std::_Tuple_impl<2ul, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> > >]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/tuple:170:17: error: ‘constexpr std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>::_Tuple_impl(const std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>&) [with long unsigned int _Idx = 2ul, _Head = std::_Placeholder<2>, _Tail = {std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >}, std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...> = std::_Tuple_impl<2ul, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> > >]’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/tuple:170:17: error: use of deleted function ‘constexpr std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>::_Tuple_impl(const std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>&) [with long unsigned int _Idx = 3ul, _Head = std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >, _Tail = {}, std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...> = std::_Tuple_impl<3ul, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> > >]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/tuple:170:17: error: ‘constexpr std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>::_Tuple_impl(const std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>&) [with long unsigned int _Idx = 3ul, _Head = std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >, _Tail = {}, std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...> = std::_Tuple_impl<3ul, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> > >]’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/tuple:170:17: error: use of deleted function ‘std::_Head_base<3ul, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >, false>::_Head_base(const std::_Head_base<3ul, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >, false>&)’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/tuple:91:12: error: ‘std::_Head_base<3ul, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >, false>::_Head_base(const std::_Head_base<3ul, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >, false>&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/tuple:91:12: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul>, _Dp = std::default_delete<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp> = std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/unique_ptr.h:256:7: error: declared here
```

Update:

I understand that the above doesn't seem to work. But then, shouldn't the following work?

```
  std::unique_ptr<buffer_t> buffer = buffers.pop();

  auto t = std::bind(&tcp_client::handle_read_done,
             this,
             std::placeholders::_1,
             std::placeholders::_2,
             std::move(buffer));
  size_t var = 10;
  boost::system::error_code code;
  t(code, var);
```

Where the signature of `handle_read_done` is

```
void tcp_client::handle_read_done(const boost::system::error_code & error, size_t bytes_read, std::unique_ptr<buffer_t> buffer)
```

It feels like I am missing something very obvious.

Error message:

```
/home/max/dev/rcon/src/net/tcp_client.cpp: In member function ‘void rcon::net::tcp_client::handle_connect_done(const boost::system::error_code&, const string&)’:
/home/max/dev/rcon/src/net/tcp_client.cpp:101:15: error: no match for call to ‘(std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (rcon::net::tcp_client::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>(rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>) (boost::system::error_code&, size_t&)’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/functional:1130:11: note: candidates are:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/functional:1201:2: note: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {_Args ...}, _Result = _Result, _Functor = std::_Mem_fn<void (rcon::net::tcp_client::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>, _Bound_args = {rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >}]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/functional:1215:2: note: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {_Args ...}, _Result = _Result, _Functor = std::_Mem_fn<void (rcon::net::tcp_client::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>, _Bound_args = {rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >}]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/functional:1229:2: note: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) volatile [with _Args = {_Args ...}, _Result = _Result, _Functor = std::_Mem_fn<void (rcon::net::tcp_client::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>, _Bound_args = {rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >}]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/functional:1243:2: note: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const volatile [with _Args = {_Args ...}, _Result = _Result, _Functor = std::_Mem_fn<void (rcon::net::tcp_client::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >)>, _Bound_args = {rcon::net::tcp_client*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 10240ul> >}]
```

Comment: How are you calling async_read_some? This will need to fill the buffer for you, it takes a boost::asio::buffer as the first parameter followed by the callback (see: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp for an example). Normally the buffer is a class member, and does not need to be passed to the callback as an argument, ergo there is no need to bind it

Comment: @mark I am constructing a boost::asio::buffer from a reference to the buffer. Then I would like to place the std::unique_ptr<buffer> in the callback, which ensures that the buffer lives on. I will then place it back into the queue in the callback.

Comment: Based on Howard's answer below it looks like the functor created by `std::bind` is not compatible with `std::function` or `boost::asio`. Ergo you have 2 options, either hold the `unique_ptr<buffer>` in a member variable, that way it will not need to be passed through `std::bind`, or switch from `std::unique_ptr` to `std::shared_ptr` (or simplar type) which supports copy semantics.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`std::bind` works fine with move-only types.  However it creates a move-only functor in the process.  `std::function` requires a copy constructible functor.  It sounds like `boost::asio` does too.

When you call the move-only `bind` functor, it will pass its bound arguments as lvalues to the target operator().  So if one of your bound arguments is move-only, the target operator() must take that argument by (possibly const) lvalue reference.

Comment: Hmm, why does std::function not work with move constructible functors?

Comment: That's good to know. I am still interested in know how async_read_some is being called.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb:  std::function type-erases its functor.  So to implement std::function's copy constructor one has to set up a virtual function to call the functor's copy constructor.  The fact that you have to point to the functor's copy constructor with a virtual function means it gets "used" whether or not you actually instantiate std::function's copy constructor.

Comment: @Howard Thank you, that sounds reasonable. I'll probably move to shared_ptr instead. However, please see my update. Why can't I even call the function?

Comment: @Howard Ah, I see. I imagine it could be possible to add a copy ctor to std::function in all cases that calls the virtual function to copy the functor. The implementation of the virtual function knows the type `Functor`, and could go like `return throw_if_noncopyable(_theFunctor);` (throw if noncopyable, and copy if it is copyable). Since this is a compiletime branch, the copy ctor would only be used if the type is copyable. Is this not workable?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb:  That sounds like it could work, though I haven't prototyped it up.  I'm not sure if it would be a good idea to have a type for which is_copy_constructible answered true, and yet the copy constructor *always* throws an exception (or assert is another possibility).  It would be kind of like handling radioactive waste:  don't trip! :-)

Comment: @Howard since it is type-erased, having it fail on runtime doesn't look too bad to me. Note that it will not *always* throw. You can assign to it a functor that is copyable, and it will not throw anymore. Just like you could have an empty std::function, and its operator() will then throw.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb:  Fair enough.  If you want to make it happen, here is the best way to do it:  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#submit_issue :-)

Comment: @Howard Eelis just had an excellent idea. Just make it `std::function<X> y = fake_copyable(move_only_object);`. Then `fake_copyable_t` just throws if it is to be copied. :)

Comment: perhaps I'm misunderstanding something, but I cannot seem to get std::bind (in clang) to work with a bound move-only object. example: https://godbolt.org/g/UP16QM

Comment: You are misunderstanding the 2nd paragraph in my answer.  Your example target function is demanding an rvalue argument.  `bind` will supply an lvalue argument.