# std::function with unique_ptr argument

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, std-function, stdbind

Given a function like

```
void MyFunction(std::unique_ptr<int> arg);
```

it is not possible (MSVC 2012) to create a functor like

```
std::function<void(std::unique_ptr<int>)> f = std::bind(&MyFunction, std::placeholders::_1);
```

The problem is not the bind - using `auto f = std::bind(...)` works. Also, using a `shared_ptr` also works

- Why is unique_ptr disallowed?
- Is this a MSVC problem or general C++11 restriction?
- Is there a work-around without changing the function definition?

Comment: Note this is not the same as `std::bind(&MyFunction, std::unique_ptr())` which has been addressed, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955714/does-stdbind-work-with-move-only-types-in-general-and-stdunique-ptr-in-part

Comment: What do you mean by _"It is not possible to create a functor"_? Your code compiles for me perfectly. [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=fc07eb6c07adb3b78b1b8546706c066c-df8dcf008f5684150551e8d7e183dfe4).

Comment: Question updated with compiler info, are you using gcc?

Comment: Both g++ and clang++. Could you post a compiler errors, please?

Comment: A million lines of template errors, most nested being:
`VC\include\functional(1152): error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>` - so it appears a copy is being attempted somewhere, I wouldn't have thought that would be necessary in this case. If you have it working in g++ this would appear to be MS specific, not surprising given the varying levels of support for C++11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below compiles fine using gcc 4.8. You will notice that 
if "g" is not called with move (that converts the lvalue to an rvalue), 
the code fails to compile. As mentioned earlier, the bind succeeds because
the failure only happens when operator()( ... ) is called, because of the
fact that unique_ptr is not copyable. The call "f" is permissible, as 
shared_ptr has a copy constructor.

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>


void foo1( std::shared_ptr<int> ){}
void foo2( std::unique_ptr<int> ){}

int main() 
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;

    std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<int>)> f = std::bind( foo1, _1 );
    std::function<void(std::unique_ptr<int>)> g = std::bind( foo2, _1 );

    std::unique_ptr<int> i( new int(5) );
    g( move( i ) ); //Requires the move

    std::shared_ptr<int> j( new int(5) );
    f( j ); //Works fine without the move
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems to suggest this is a MSVC problem - good to know the code is legal.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to have

```
void MyFunction(std::unique_ptr<int>& arg)
```

but that doesn't work if you can't change the function definition.