# Binding functions with unique_ptr arguments to std::function<void()>

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to make the following code work:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(): m_str("foo") { }

    void f1(string s1, string s2, unique_ptr<Foo> p)
        {
            printf("1: %s %s %s\n", s1.c_str(), s2.c_str(), p->str());
        }

    void f2(string s1, string s2, Foo* p)
        {
            printf("2: %s %s %s\n", s1.c_str(), s2.c_str(), p->str());
        }

    const char* str() const { return m_str.c_str(); }

private:
    string m_str;
};

int main()
{
    string arg1 = "arg1";
    string arg2 = "arg2";
    Foo s;
    unique_ptr<Foo> ptr(new Foo);


    //function<void()> f(bind(&Foo::f1, &s, arg1, arg2, std::move(ptr)));
    function<void()> f(bind(&Foo::f2, &s, arg1, arg2, ptr.release()));

    f();
}
```

Calling `f()` bound to `Foo::f2` (last parameter is a raw pointer) works fine, but binding it to `Foo::f1` causes compilation error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:36:70: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::function<void()>::function(std::_Bind_helper<false, void (Foo::*)(std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Foo>), Foo*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::unique_ptr<Foo, std::default_delete<Foo> > >::type)’
     function<void()> f(bind(&Foo::f1, &s, arg1, arg2, std::move(ptr)));
                                                                      ^
test.cpp:36:70: note: candidates are:
In file included from test.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:2251:2: note: template<class _Functor, class> std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor)
  function(_Functor);
  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:2251:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:2226:7: note: std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&&) [with _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {}]
       function(function&& __x) : _Function_base()
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:2226:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::_Bind_helper<false, void (Foo::*)(std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Foo>), Foo*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::unique_ptr<Foo, std::default_delete<Foo> > >::type {aka std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (Foo::*)(std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Foo>)>(Foo*, std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Foo>)>}’ to ‘std::function<void()>&&’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:2429:5: note: std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(const std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&) [with _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {}]
     function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>::
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:2429:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::_Bind_helper<false, void (Foo::*)(std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Foo>), Foo*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::unique_ptr<Foo, std::default_delete<Foo> > >::type {aka std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (Foo::*)(std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Foo>)>(Foo*, std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Foo>)>}’ to ‘const std::function<void()>&’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:2206:7: note: std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(std::nullptr_t) [with _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {}; std::nullptr_t = std::nullptr_t]
       function(nullptr_t) noexcept
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:2206:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::_Bind_helper<false, void (Foo::*)(std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Foo>), Foo*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::unique_ptr<Foo, std::default_delete<Foo> > >::type {aka std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (Foo::*)(std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Foo>)>(Foo*, std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<Foo>)>}’ to ‘std::nullptr_t’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:2199:7: note: std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function() [with _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {}]
       function() noexcept
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:2199:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using gcc 4.8.2 and `-std=c++0x` (`-std=c++11` fails too) flags.

Comment: There are issues with passing rvalues to std::bind, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871273/passing-rvalues-through-stdbind Does f1 really need to acquire ownership of the pointer? f1 could take the pointer by const ref and then you can pass the pointer to std::bind using std::ref http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ebe39ccca544bea

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955714/does-stdbind-work-with-move-only-types-in-general-and-stdunique-ptr-in-part

Comment: @justinls Yup, it needs to take ownership, but thanks for your example. If I don't find a way to make it work using std::move, I'll propose a workaround using your suggestion

Comment: Why do you use std::move if you your function doesn't take a r-value reference to your unique pointer (std::unique_ptr<Foo> &&) ?

Answer (score 12):

The issues with bind described in the other answers (as of this writing) are not what the compiler is complaining about in the question. The problem is  that `std::function` must be CopyConstructible, which requires its argument (which will be stored by the function) also be CopyConstructible.

From the standard [20.9.11.2 Class template function]

```
template<class F> function(F f); 
template <class F, class A> function(allocator_arg_t, const A& a, F f);
```

> Requires: F shall be CopyConstructible. f shall be Callable (20.9.11.2) for argument types ArgTypes and return type R . The copy constructor and destructor of A shall not throw exceptions...

Consider this example that doesn't even include bind in it:

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct NonCopyableFunctor {
  NonCopyableFunctor(){}
  NonCopyableFunctor(const NonCopyableFunctor &) = delete;
  NonCopyableFunctor(NonCopyableFunctor &&){}
  void operator()(){}
};

int main() 
{
  NonCopyableFunctor fun;
  function<void()> vfun(move(fun)); // even though I move here,
  // it still complains about a copy going on elsewhere.
}
```

Here's the output from clang:

```
[orm@localhost ~]$ clang++ -std=c++11 bound_unique.cc 
In file included from bound_unique.cc:1:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../../include/c++/4.8.2/functional:1911:10: error: call to deleted constructor of 'NonCopyableFunctor'
            new _Functor(*__source._M_access<_Functor*>());
                ^        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../../include/c++/4.8.2/functional:1946:8: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<NonCopyableFunctor>::_M_clone' requested here
              _M_clone(__dest, __source, _Local_storage());
              ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../../include/c++/4.8.2/functional:2453:33: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<NonCopyableFunctor>::_M_manager' requested here
            _M_manager = &_My_handler::_M_manager;
                                       ^
bound_unique.cc:16:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::function<void ()>::function<NonCopyableFunctor, void>' requested here
  function<void()> vfun(move(fun));
                   ^
bound_unique.cc:8:3: note: function has been explicitly marked deleted here
  NonCopyableFunctor(const NonCopyableFunctor &) = delete;
  ^
1 error generated.
```

Note that if you bind a unique_ptr, the resulting bind object will be non-copyable. Bind will still compile anyway.

Answer (score 4):

1) The following code won't compile

```
 function<void()> f(bind(&Foo::f1, &s, arg1, arg2, std::move(ptr)));
 // just define f, not even call it
```

because `function` requires the callable object is copy-constructible but when `bind` takes a non-copyable argument like `unique_ptr` the returned functor will be non-copyable, as mentioned in other answers.

2) So just don't use `function` for `bind`. However the following code won't compile either

```
 auto f(bind(&Foo::f1, &s, arg1, arg2, std::move(ptr))); // a
 f();                                                    // b
```

because at step (a) `bind` stores what you give to it as an lvalue (except for `reference_wrapper`), and passes it to the internal functor at step (b). Therefore it requires the bound arguments are copyable for those parameters are passed by value, not references.

3) Then try using the raw pointer. However the following code won't compile either

```
 auto f(bind(&Foo::f1, &s, arg1, arg2, ptr.release()));
 f();
```

A similar reason like (2), the functor stores an `int*`, and try to convert it to the parameter type `unique_ptr<int>` when called. But the constructor `unique_ptr(pointer p)` is `explicit`.

---

To compile it, you need a function like this

```
void f3(string s1, string s2, unique_ptr<Foo>& p)
//                                           ^ use reference; add const if you need
{
    printf("3: %s %s %s\n", s1.c_str(), s2.c_str(), p->str());
}

auto f(bind(&Foo::f3, &s, arg1, arg2, std::move(ptr)));
f();
```

Note that `f` could be called several times, and the parameters `p` reference the same `unique_ptr` that is stored in the returned object of `bind`.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm it really seems that std::bind has troubles when dealing with r-value references. One alternative would be to use a lambda function:

```
function<void()> f([&]() { s.f1(arg1,arg2,std::move(ptr)); });
```

In order for this to work you also have to change the signature of f1 such that it accepts the unique_ptr as an r-value reference:

```
void f1(string s1, string s2, unique_ptr<Foo>&& p)
```

(Even if std::bind could handle r-value references, you would still have to do this because std::unique_ptr doesn't have a copy constructor, only the move constructor is accessible!)

Note however that your construct is rather dangerous (also if std::bind would work): if you call f() twice, you will end up with a runtime exception.

Comment: Note that in C++11 you can't easily capture a `unique_ptr` in a lambda expression like this.  If you try this you'll get a null pointer exception at runtime, if you call the function once the original `unique_ptr` has gone out of scope.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236521/how-to-capture-a-unique-ptr-into-a-lambda-expression) for some workarounds.